# Basic Swift 3 app crashing with Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm getting started with Firebase in iOS and after going through Firebase's documentation and doing the preliminary set-up for my app, it won't run in the simulator.

Here's the error:

```
2017-01-16 10:56:08.058 Thread[18978:1562804] Firebase automatic screen reporting is enabled. Call +[FIRAnalytics setScreenName:setScreenClass:] to set the screen name or override the default screen class name. To disable automatic screen reporting, set the flag FirebaseAutomaticScreenReportingEnabled to NO in the Info.plist
2017-01-16 10:56:08.062808 Thread[18978:1562850] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: HIDEventFiltered, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2017-01-16 10:56:08.064832 Thread[18978:1562850] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: HIDEventIncoming, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2017-01-16 10:56:08.072334 Thread[18978:1562846] subsystem: com.apple.BaseBoard, category: MachPort, enable_level: 1, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0, enable_private_data: 0
2017-01-16 10:56:08.083044 Thread[18978:1562804] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: StatusBar, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
(lldb)
```

and here's the current state of my AppDelegate.swift (only made changes for setting up Firebase)

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        FIRApp.configure()
        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }


}
```

It's getting hung up on FIRApp.configure()

Comment: That's not the error - it looks like the app is paused at a breakpoint - you'll probably need to continue it to see the proper error.

Comment: I suspect your project might be missing the `GoogleService-Info.plist` file?

Comment: .plist file is there and it doesn't seem to be a breakpoint. I certainly didn't (intentionally) set one and the breakpoint navigator isn't showing anything. Thanks for the responses though!

Comment: Import FirebaseDatabase? Are you in the xcworkspace?

Comment: What happens when FIRApp.Config is commented out? Also, how did you install Firebase - through Cocoapods? Lastly, are you opening the project with the xcworkspace file?

Comment: When commented out it runs fine. Installed through cocoapods. Yes, opening through xcworkspace

Comment: What does your podFile look like? Also, have you updated your Cocoapods recently?

Comment: Installed Cocoapods for this project yesterday so I'd think it's up-to-date.
Podfile:
target 'Thread' do

  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'

  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Thread

  target 'ThreadTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'ThreadUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end

Answer (score 0):

Did you added to the bundle "GoogleService-Info.plist"?

You have to bundle the GoogleService-Info.plist then only library can autofind the location and use it.